# Convert a three-level hierarchical data into a specific json format

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a three-level hierarchical dataset, like below:

```
pd.DataFrame({'level1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
               'level2': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'B1' ],
                'level3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                'value': [44, 125, 787, 99, 111],
                'pctChg': [0.3, -0.9, -10.0, 12, -0.2]})


  level1    level2  level3  value   pctChg
0   A       A1      a       44       0.3
1   A       A1      b       125     -0.9
2   A       A2      c       787     -10.0
3   A       A2      d       99      12.0
4   B       B1      e       111     -0.2
```

For a specific level1 category like `A`, there are level2 category like `A1, A2`. 
under levels two, there are many level3 categories. For example, 'a' and 'b' are under 'A1', 
'c' and 'd' are under A2. This data is just an example. For each combination, there are value and percent info (percentage change from last month).

I need to tranform this data into a nested json data. It needs to be the format like below:

```
{
    name: “root”,
    value: 1166,
    pctChg: xx%,
    children: [
    {
        name: 'A',
        value: 956,
        pctChg: 'xx%'',
        children: [{
            name: 'A1',
            value: 169,
            pctChg: 'xx%'',
            children: [{name: 'a', value: 44, pctChg: '30%'},
                       {name:'b', value:125, pctChg: '-90%'},
                       {name:'c', value:787, pctChg: '-10%'}           
            ]
        },  .....]
    },
.....…
    ]
    }
```

We also need to aggregate the value for a level from all childrens at one level down.
Value can be aggragated obviously.  One tricky part is percent. We might not want to simply aggregate the percentage.

This looks like a pretty difficult task. Not like some simple nested json data.  I'm not sure how I can approach that. Appreciate if anyone can help.  Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Note that *pctChg* in first 2 rows (*0.3* and *0.9*) is converted to the target string by multiplying by 100 and adding "%" char.
But in the third row you want source value *-10.0* is to be converted to *-10%*,
i.e. **without** such multiplication (assume rounding to integer number).
Either make up your mind about the multiplication factor or define the rule
how to convert source *pctChg* to the target (JSON) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to reformat *pctChg* column to percentage string:

```
df.pctChg = (df.pctChg * 100).astype(int).astype(str) + '%'
```

(I assumed *multiply by 100* formula).

Then define 2 functions computing children of the second and first level:

```
def chld2(grp):
    return grp.rename(columns={'level3': 'name'}).groupby('level2')\
        .apply(lambda grp: pd.Series({'name': grp.iloc[0,1], 'value': grp.value.sum(),
        'pctChg': 'xx%', 'children': grp[['name', 'value', 'pctChg']].to_dict('r') }))\
        .to_dict('r')

def chld1(df):
    return df.groupby('level1').apply(lambda grp: pd.Series({
        'name': grp.iloc[0,0], 'value': grp.value.sum(), 'pctChg': 'xx%',
        'children': chld2(grp)})).to_dict('r')
```

And to generate the result, run:

```
pd.Series({'name': 'root', 'value': df.value.sum(), 'pctChg': 'xx%',
    'children': chld1(df)}).to_json()
```

The result (with manually added indentation for readability) is:

```
{ "name":"root", "value":1166, "pctChg":"xx%",
  "children":[
    { "name":"A", "value":1055, "pctChg":"xx%",
      "children":[
        { "name":"A1", "value":169, "pctChg":"xx%",
          "children":[
            {"name":"a", "value":44, "pctChg":"30%"},
            {"name":"b", "value":125, "pctChg":"-90%"}
          ]
        },
        { "name":"A2", "value":886, "pctChg":"xx%",
          "children":[
            {"name":"c", "value":787, "pctChg":"-1000%"},
            {"name":"d", "value":99, "pctChg":"1200%"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    { "name":"B", "value":111, "pctChg":"xx%",
      "children":[
        { "name":"B1", "value":111, "pctChg":"xx%",
          "children":[
            {"name":"e", "value":111, "pctChg":"-20%"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Super thanks!  Just one thing:  xx% is for 'aggregated' percent change for childrens under that level .  I'm not totally clear how that should be done.  I'm thinking  the average of percentage of all children under the level weighted by value. so for A1, it might be   (44x0.3+125x(-0.9))/(44+125).   How should we implement that? @Valdi_Bo

Comment: In your post you wrote *We might not want to simply aggregate the percentage* and I came up with a solution reflecting this point. Now you attempt to change it. This is rather a material for **another** question.